# Wish to write two lists into one column of csv file using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']/span[1]")

reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']/span[2]")
```

I am iterating the reviewText list values appending into the list Reviews. And in another for loop, doing the same process, iterating the values of the list reviewFullText and writing into the list Reviews2.

```
for txtrev in reviewText:
    Reviews.append(txtrev.text)

for txtrev2 in reviewFullText:
    Reviews2.append(txtrev2.text)
```

Writing 2 lists into 1 csv file using Pandas dataframe, but the values are coming in 2 columns, but i want to merge the 2 lists where 1st list of index values (say if Reviews[4] and Reviews[6] are null means, Reviews2[4] and Reviews2[6] values needs to be placed there, literally I don't want nulls and whitespaces in csv file at all), likewise I need to merge these 2 lists so that I could get values in 1 column alone. For example, if my Reviews[0], Reviews[1], Reviews[2] having some text content, (actually, google play store reviews), Reviews which are not captured in span[1] will get captured from span[2], so Reviews2[0], Reviews2[1], Reviews2[2] will have null in this case, Reviews2[3] will have text content, alternatively any of one list item will have text content (Reviews[10] having content means, Reviews2[10] wont have text, Reviews[11] doesn't have content, Reviews2[11] will have it)

Here in dataframe, I need to fill Reviews[] first then, Reviews2[] should get filled in the same column where the Reviews[] list are having null values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Reviews,Reviews2)
df.to_csv('Reviews.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide a short example of the two lists with an attribute missing and how you want the dataframe to look like in that case?

Comment: added details about list, please check now.. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't help. Please provide 4-5 elements for both `reviewText` and `reviewFullText` with some elements missing the actual output of your dataframe given those elements.

Comment: Pls find the below list details:- `Reviews[] = ['This app is a crash fest and I hate it. It makes the app completely ....','I have the same general issues that most people have had','',''] , Reviews2[] = ['','','app is working fine and cool'.'app getting crashed often']` , while merging both these lists into one csv file, I want it in one column, by using _dataframe_ or any other libraries of **Python** also fine.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still am not entirely sure I undertand you completely, but this may get you started:

```
import pandas as pd:

Reviews = ['This app is a crash','I have the same general','','']  
Reviews2 = ['','','app is working','app getting crashed often']
rev3 =[]

for x,y in zip(Reviews,Reviews2):
    if len(x)>0:
        rev3.append(x)
    else:
        rev3.append(y)
pd.DataFrame(rev3)
```

Output:

```
    0
0   This app is a crash
1   I have the same general
2   app is working
3   app getting crashed often
```